# renew expire certificates then can't receive push notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am new to iOS develop this is first time for me to handle certificate which has been expired. After I renew certificate and replace it to server, I am not receiving push notification. I may did some mistake. Please correct me.

Below are the steps i followed:

**step1--**  Recreate push notification, production type is "Apple Push Services" I know apple do some change, but the development type still is "APNs ..."

If I can use new certificate for development and production environment why apple provide develop choice?

**step2--**  I also found the Ad Hoc certificate will expire, so I also recreate it, both development and production

**step3--**  Of course I recreate provisioning profiles, but when I create for development I can't distinguish which certificate is new one, so I revoked the old one.

**step4--**  Install new certificates and provisioning profile in my mac, then export p12 to server.

Then I can't receive push notification, someone said the new certificate need to update program to fix it, I hope after edit the code push notification will work fine.

But how about development push notification? the development certificate type is the same but I still can't receive push notification, or it caused by renew Ad Hoc certificate ?

========== edit at 3/3 ========
Because the new type of certificate can use for development and production at the same time, so after server side update its code, I test push notification with the new type of certificate both development and production, and this time I get push notification.

Maybe because I have new type of certificate so APNs doesn't accept old type of certificate, is it possible?

Comment: .pem file or .p12 files  creates from new certificates should be used for sending notifications after deleting old one.

Comment: sure, I send new .p12 file to server

Answer (score 0):

Go to Keychain Access, delete all expired certificates. Regenerate your push notification certificates from Developer Center along with new provisional profile.

Comment: I do test by [pusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher), sometimes I get push notifications and sometimes not

Comment: If sometimes your notifications get fired, then its not a certificate related problem, it has to be from your server or pusher side. I would suggest you to repeat entire process after clearing your keychain and possibly push certificates from your developer center.